# How to use a NSString method to return a string?

Tags: function, methods, nsstring, format

Given a function like this:

```
    - (NSString *) changemystringsomehow
{
    // do something to the string / check the string
    return ?;
}
```

How would I use this in another function to get the 'changed' string back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, read the * manual they say. I find the documentation to be incomprehensible sometimes but I gave it a shot. I found the answer and learned how to make a category.

[customize existing classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)